# Monitoring several Raspberry Pi

Tags: arm, sensu

I have several Raspberry Pi computers running, and they're currently using smtp to tell me what's going on Error reporting etc. But I'd really like to find a better way. I found Sensu, but perhaps it's overkill.

1. Have you tried Sensu on a Raspberry?
2. Are there any other monitoring solutions you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I havent tried sensu on raspberry pi, but the sensu-client gem is extremely light weight. There is a [check-tail](https://github.com/sensu/sensu-community-plugins/blob/master/plugins/files/check-tail.rb) check that might help you with checking your errors.

Btw, it does seem that the [raspberry pi](http://rayhightower.com/blog/2012/12/03/ruby-on-raspberry-pi/) does run ruby.

The dashboard is great also, being that it uses rabbitmq on the backend, you can have multiple machines checkin without having to configure each over and over.

Do you have a static amount of Pis? Or are you planning on fluctuating?

I strongly suggest against nagios/nrpe for something that already has lower than normal resources.

Answer (score 0):

I use [telegraf](https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.5/) with influxdb ang grafana for the monitoring. And [Monit](https://mmonit.com/) for the proactive monitoring for my Pis.